# PHP key value pairs, where key is a dynamic variable and value is an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, keyvaluepair

I am trying to create a 2D array where `$multiples[$i] = array(multiples of $i), $i = 1,2,3..`.

```
function getMultiples($factor, $start = 0, 10)
{
  $multiples = array();

  for($i = $factor + $start; $i < 10; $i+=$factor)
  $multiples[] = $i;

  return $multiples;
}

for($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $start = 0 ;

    $multiples[$i] = getMultiples($i, $start, 10);
}
```

However, when I `var_dump`

```
$multiples[2] = array(0 => 2)
$multiples[3] = array(0 => 3)
$multiples[4] = array(0 => 4)
...
```

Each element of `$values` has been intialized with only the first multiple in each array.

I've tested this with non-numerical key values and it works fine. Static key values also work. The dynamic key value `$i` seems to the problem, what is going on here?

Comment: I tried it and work well, each item in `$values` is array of three elements

Comment: Hmm you're right it does work... but this is a simplified version of my problem where it isn't working. So maybe the problem lies elsewhere! I'm going to dig around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the multiples of a number, you need to update the `getMultiples` as following:

```
function getMultiples($factor, $start = 0, $max)
{
  $multiples = array();

  for($i = 2; $i < $max; $i++)
  $multiples[] = $i*$factor;

  return $multiples;
}
```

What we change?

1. Loop 10 or `$max` time `for($i = $factor + $start; $i < 10; $i+=$factor)` **to** `for($i = 2; $i < $max; $i++)`.
2. Find multiple `$multiples[] = $i;` **to** `$multiples[] = $i*$factor;`

Comment: Both ways work but I think yours is neater - I'm over-complicating things as usual :) I found out the problem in my code - a few lines along I used `array_splice` instead of `array_slice` resulting in the truncated array!